# Can I have dual monitors on my MacBook Pro (Early 2011)?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro (13") from Early 2011 and want to use 1 external monitor as extended monitor. When I connect my Xiaomi Redmi 1A 23.8" Monitor in Mini Display Port Using HDMI to DP adapter. The new connected monitors appears under displays but not showing anything in it.

Is there any way for me to have that displays work, I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 (17G14042)?

Comment: @SolarMike No it’s not the answer for me

Comment: ***How*** does it not answer the question?  In other words, what about the question is so significantly different than your question?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of any problem is the adaptor. It's also the easiest/cheapest part to replace and test with alternatives.

However, it's always possible that a 12-year-old computer won't be compatible with a much newer device, for whatever reason.

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I tried replacing adaptor & current one is working with other devices.